# Color Vignette Core Image filter for iOS?

Tags: ios, ios8, core-image

I have tested the vignette filter in Core Image, while good - I am wondering whether anyone has implemented color vignette effect (instead of black edges, it soften the edges) by chaining through various Core Image filters for iOS? Or points me to a tutorial to do this?

Based on the answer below, this is my code - but does not seem to have much effect.

```
func colorVignette(image:UIImage) -> UIImage {
    let cimage = CIImage(image:image)
    let whiteImage = CIImage(image:colorImage(UIColor.whiteColor(), size:image.size))

    var output1 = CIFilter(name:"CIGaussianBlur", withInputParameters:[kCIInputImageKey:cimage, kCIInputRadiusKey:5]).outputImage
    var output2 = CIFilter(name:"CIVignette", withInputParameters:[kCIInputImageKey:whiteImage, kCIInputIntensityKey:vignette, kCIInputRadiusKey:1]).outputImage
    var output = CIFilter(name:"CIBlendWithMask", withInputParameters:[kCIInputImageKey:cimage, kCIInputMaskImageKey:output2, kCIInputBackgroundImageKey:output1]).outputImage

    return UIImage(CGImage:ctx.createCGImage(output, fromRect:cimage.extent()))
}

func colorImage(color:UIColor, size:CGSize) -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
    color.setFill()
    UIRectFill(CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:size.width, height:size.height))
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return image
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a filter by chaining together a Gaussian Blur, a Vignette, a Blend With Mask and the original image. First blur the input image with a `CIGaussianBlur`. Next, apply the `CIVignette` filter to a solid white image of the same size. Finally, mix the original image with the blurred image using the [`CIBlendWithMask`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIBlendWithMask) filter.

Comment: I tried and does not seem to have much effect, I attached my code above.

Comment: Can you upload a picture of what you're getting? (If you don't have enough rep, just upload it to a free image hosting site, and I'll add it to your post.)

Comment: OK, but just to note - they look identical to me.

Comment: You can try to do it in steps. For example, output just the blurred image and see if it's correct. If so, output the white image and see if it's correct. If so, output the white image with vignette and see if it's correct, etc. Perhaps your mask isn't right, or something like that and the output is just the input because the mask is entirely white or black or something?

Comment: I have been testing and found an easier receipt: 1) CIGaussianBlur image, 2) create CIRadialGradient mask, 3) use CIBlendWithMask to merge blur image and image together, with the radial mask! Looks cool.

Comment: Awesome! Good luck with it!